# How do I round a float in money?

Tags: python

So I am having a bit of trouble rounding a float in python.

This is what my output looks like

```
Here is your receipt:
Coffe £ 1.2
HotChocolate £ 2.0
Latte £ 3.9000000000000004
Cappucino £ 2.2
Cake £ 1.5
Pensioner Yes
Takeout Yes
Total Cost: 11.664000000000001
```

How would I round up the value to 2 dp?

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please read [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python).
If its just in printing:
print("%.2f" % float)

Comment: It is generally considered that `float` is unsafe for money amounts.  See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406737/what-class-to-use-for-money-representation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560455/decimals-to-2-places-for-money-in-python-3

Answer (score 4):

Sample examples:

```
>>> x = 11.664000000000001
>>> 
>>> round(x, 2)
11.66
>>> 
>>> '{:0.2f}'.format(x)
'11.66'
>>> 
>>> '%0.2f' % x
'11.66'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The floats has a propertie, they are non exacts, because of the architecture of the machine, python has it limitation too, try printing like:

```
print("%.2f" % some_float)
```

This question has everything you need:

[Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)